# Does most firewalls default configuration allow secured TCP the same as HTTPS?

Tags: networking, ssl, tcp, https, firewall

I need to implement secure data transfer from client to server (binary data). I'm looking for the solution that doesn't require clients to configure firewall exceptions.

Obvious choice is HTTPS. Most firewalls allow outgoing HTTPS by default. There're two issues with HTTPS:

1. I don't want to implement HTTPS (even the simplest possible version) because I don't need its complexity. Simple custom secure binary protocol would be enough.
2. I'd like to avoid overhead of base64 encoding required for binary data to be put into HTTP POST message (please correct me if I'm wrong). Client runs on weak hardware (embedded system).

Now, my assumptions. Since HTTPS is encrypted (by definition), firewall cannot parse it or check if data is base64 encoded. This means I can use my custom TCP secured protocol using HTTPS port (443) to imitate HTTPS and firewall won't be able to distinguish it from HTTPS. Please confirm or explain what's my mistake.

Comment: Why do you think that there is a 'simple binary' protocol that is secure enough for you, other than https? Why do you think that firewalls are too stupid to notice transactions that are not the standard setup transactions of TLS?

Comment: @bmargulies: I meant "custom **secure** TCP protocol", i.e. over SSL connection. Edited the question. This level of security is enough for my needs.

Comment: https is just HTTP over ssl. What complexity are you hoping to remove? HTTP is an awfully simple protocol. You don't have to base64 the contents of a post, it can be arbitrary bytes with a suitable content type. Lots of REST-ful services work this way.

Comment: to implement limited but functional HTTP server I need to parse HTTP messages to check that they are only POSTs (I don't need others), to check headers (server supports single predefined type of binary data), to retrieve "Content-Length" parameter etc. And what is more, I need to read HTTP RFC because I've never done this before and I don't won't to implement HTTP server w/o clear understanding what I'm doing. In contrast to this, custom protocol can be: content-length[4 bytes, big-endian], content[content-length bytes]. This really looks simpler.

Comment: another option is to use one of many existing open-source HTTP servers. But again this looks more complicated than *two-fields* *stateless* custom protocol

Comment: I'm a little confused. Base64 is unacceptable overhead, but SSL/TLS is fine? Unless you have your SSL/TLS fully offloaded onto dedicated crypto processors, its so much more expensive than Base64 that its not funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO a firewall is not really a good firewall, unless the "default" configuration is to deny everything in/out (for instance, this is what a Juniper SRX and Cisco ASA do by default).  The *most common firewall configurations* typically allow HTTPS through.

As for building your own custom protocol, please for the love of pizza (and your own sanity) use one of the many standardized file transfer protocols that already exist... the choices are wide open, such as `ftp`, `rsync`, `http` (see below), `scp`, and `sftp`.

Two things you need to think about...

- The first thing you need to worry about is if your clients perform some kind of deep packet inspection to verify that you aren't just tunneling "other stuff" through TCP/443.  This isn't common today, but some people do it.
- Another point, some people (you may be surprised at how many) get a generic SSL certificate and build a transparent proxy for all http/https.  That *will* mess your plans up; at this point you need https and POST.

Comment: +1, especially for transparent proxy, I didn't think about this. custom protocol would be so simple that using any general-purpose protocol looks like an overkill in all aspects: implementation complexity, 3rd-party dependency, performance etc. But that transparent proxy idea makes me think twice. about sftp and others, aren't they less popular as firewall default exceptions?

Comment: @Andy T, yes transparent HTTP/HTTPS proxy is less common in residential firewalls, but significantly more common in corporate environments