# How to correctly send binary data over HTTPS POST?

Tags: c++, ssl, https, boost-asio

I send binary data from client (Debian 6.0.3) to server (Windows Server 2003). To bypass most firewalls I use **HTTPS POST**. Client and server are implemented using **Boost.Asio** and **OpenSSL**. First I implemented the simplest possible version and it worked fine.

**HTTP Header:**

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: my custom client v.1

[binary data]
```

(`[binary data]` is not base64 encoded if this matters)

Then, on another client machine it failed (connected to the same server machine). The behavior is not stable. Connection always is established fine (port 443). Most time I pass SSL handshake fine but server receive no data (almost no data, sometimes a packet or two are actually received). Sometimes I receive SSL handshake error "short read". Sometimes I receive invalid data.

Client connects to server, handshakes, sends HTTP POST header and then infinitely sends binary data until something wrong hapenned. For test I use custom generated SSL certificate.

**Server code:**

```
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
ssl::context context(io_service, ssl::context::sslv23);
context.set_options(ssl::context::default_workarounds | ssl::context::no_sslv2);
context.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
context.use_private_key_file("server.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket(io_service, context);

// standard connection accepting

socket.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::server, ...);
...
boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, POST_header, "\r\n\r\n", ...);
...
```

**Client code:**

```
ssl::context context(io_service, ssl::context::sslv23);
context.load_verify_file("server.crt");
socket.reset(new ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(io_service, context));
socket->set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);

// standard connection

socket.async_handshake(ssl::stream_base::client, ...);
...
```

(error handling is omitted along with not relevant code)

As you can see, it's the simplest possible SSL connection. What is wrong? Can the reason be a firewall?

I tried simple TCP w/o SSL over the same 443 port, this works fine.

**EDIT:**

Tried adding "Content-Type: application/octet-stream", doesn't help.

**EDIT 2:**

Usually I receive HTTP POST header fine. Then I send data chunks as `chunk-size(4 bytes)chunk(chunk-size bytes)...`. Server receives `chunk-size` fine, but then nothing. Client doesn't notify server problems (no errors) and continue to send data. Sometimes server can receive chunk or two, sometimes it receives invalid `chunk-size`, but most time just nothing.

**EDIT 3:**

Compared captured traffic on client and server, didn't find any differences.

**Solution**

I was misled from the start with this problem. Narrowed it down to surprising details:

Sending over SSL socket fails if I use Boost.Asio multi-buffers in Boost v.1.48 (the most recent one at this moment). Example:

```
// data to send, protocol is [packet size: 4 bytes][packet: packet_size bytes]
std::vector<char> packet = ...;
uint32_t packet_size = packet.size();
// prepare buffers
boost::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 2> bufs = {{boost::asio::buffer(&packet_size, sizeof(packet_size)), boost::asio::buffer(packet)}};
// send multi buffers by single call
boost::asio::async_write(socket, bufs, ...);
```

Sending separately `packet_size` and `packet` in this example works around the problem. I'm far from calling any suspicious behavior as a bug, especially if it's related with Boost libraries. But this one really looks like a bug. Tried on Boost v.1.47 - works fine. Tried with usual TCP socket (not SSL one) - works fine. The same on both Linux and Windows.

I'm going to find any reports about this problem in Asio mailing list and will report it if nothing found.

Comment: Does it work without use of SSL? Are you sure the binary data doesn't contain embedded newlines?

Comment: @AlanStokes: it works, at least on another client machines during long tests. Embedded data can contain anything, does it matter?

Comment: @AlanStokes: sorry, the prev comment is inaccurate: it works w/o SSL on this machine and it works with SSL on another machines. I just cannot understand what's the difference. Those machines are located in different networks. It's why I suspected firewall, but rechecked and found nothing.

Comment: I suggest you try Wireshark on the working and non-working and compare. (Easier with SSL off, of course.)

Comment: @AlanStokes: yeah, tried to analyze traffic. On both sides I see the same: "client->server: TLSv1 Application Data, Application Data, ...", "server->client: TCP https -> some port [ACK] ..."

Comment: @AndyT, any difference in packet lengths, fragmentation or ICMP messages? Have you tried to change some buffer sizes?

Comment: @Bruno: usually I see couple of "Application Data" chunks in a packet in Wireshark. Didn't notice ICMP messages. What buffer size should I change and for what? Will compare Wireshark data on client and server side on Monday, tnx for idea

Comment: @Bruno: compared captured packets, didn't find any differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was misled from the start with this problem. Narrowed it down to surprising details:

Sending over SSL socket fails if I use Boost.Asio multi-buffers in Boost v.1.48 (the most recent one at this moment). Example:

```
// data to send, protocol is [packet size: 4 bytes][packet: packet_size bytes]
std::vector<char> packet = ...;
uint32_t packet_size = packet.size();
// prepare buffers
boost::array<boost::asio::const_buffer, 2> bufs = {{boost::asio::buffer(&packet_size, sizeof(packet_size)), boost::asio::buffer(packet)}};
// send multi buffers by single call
boost::asio::async_write(socket, bufs, ...);
```

Sending separately `packet_size` and `packet` in this example works around the problem. I'm far from calling any suspicious behavior as a bug, especially if it's related with Boost libraries. But this one really looks like a bug. Tried on Boost v.1.47 - works fine. Tried with usual TCP socket (not SSL one) - works fine. The same on both Linux and Windows.

I'm going to find any reports about this problem in Asio mailing list and will report it if nothing found.

Comment: Over a year later - was anything found?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have to operate in front of web server, you don't have
to use HTTPS protocol. From the firewall point of view HTTPS looks like yet
another SSL connection and it has no idea what going through. So if the
only thing you need is just to pass the data - not to actual web server, use
just SSL connection over 443 port.

So just troubleshoot your SSL connection the problem has nothing to do with HTTP.

---

If you want to use HTTP web server and not custom client:

Two points:

1. You need to specify Content-Length.
2. If you are using HTTP/1.1 you need to specify Host header.

The simplest would be

```
POST /url HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: my custom client v.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: NNN

Actual Content
```

Or for HTTP/1.1

```
POST /url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: my custom client v.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: NNN

Actual Content
```

**Note:** you can't send infinite data. HTTP protocol requires fixed content-lenght
and most of the time web servers would load the data first before passing it to the
backend.

So you will have to transfer data by chunks.

Comment: Some firewalls use [transparent proxies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794377/453271) to control SSL connections, hence simulating HTTPS. Both client and server are implemented by me. I don't know `content-length` because my data is endless stream, but I'll try to specify some large value to check if this matters. Usually I receive HTTP POST header and the first data chunk size fine on server. Added some info to the question.

Comment: If you do not know the size of the stream up front, then DO NOT use the `Content-Length` header at all. Its value MUST match the total size being sent. You will need to send the stream data in chunks using an HTTP 1.1 request with the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header instead.

Comment: @Andy T That means that transparent proxy knows your private key... or the SSL client ignores man-in-the-middle attack or does not verify the SSL certificate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: resolved the problem, please see my answer or updated question

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT: I had originally deleted this because I had realised it wasn't using HTTP really. Following a comment where you think you might have a MITM proxy and should use proper HTTP, I'm undeleting/editing.)

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: my custom client v.1

[binary data]
```

Whether it's binary data or not, in plain HTTP or with SSL/TLS, you'll need a `Content-Length` header or to use [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). This [this section](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) of the HTTP spec. A `Content-Type` header would be useful too.

Chunked transfer encoding is for when you don't necessarily know the length of the stream. (You always need some form of delimiters when sending data, if only to detect reliably when it ends.)

This being said, you should be able to find out whether you're behind a MITM proxy that looks into the application layer on top of SSL/TLS if you get a certificate that's not your servers. If you do still get a successful handshake with your won server cert, there isn't such a proxy. Even an HTTP proxy would use `CONNECT` and relay everything, without altering the SSL/TLS connection (and thus without altering your original pseudo-HTTP on top).

Comment: Tried to add "Content-Length: 1000000\r\n", nothing changed

Comment: The `Content-Length` would need to match the exact size of what you're sending, so chunked encoding might in general be appropriate. This being said, it would seem this is not the cause of your problem unfortunately.

Comment: resolved the problem, please see my answer or updated question